# Cannot turn on Window Effects

Tags: deepin-desktop-environment

I've installed Deepin DE on top of Ubuntu and I cannot turn on the window effects.  I click the toggle switch and it just snaps back.

Comment: Which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I hadn't rebooted after installing the NVIDIA drivers. So this morning, after starting my PC again, everything is as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Change the false in OpenGLIsUnsafe (in the kwinrc file (~/.config)) to true.

Comment: It's not clear the path of the file that is supposed to be changed, nor is it clear which line should be changed and from what to what exactly.  Consider editing your answer to remove all ambiguity.  Be exact!

Answer (score 0):

Run this command on your terminal and the problem should be resolved:

```
killall deepin-wm-switcher; deepin-wm --replace
```